# display elements related CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a page with a lot of products, i want to display only the ones with the same region as the user and region All, so if i have a user which region is Japan that user only have to see products with region All and Japan.

How can i show the products with that rectiction?

I don't know if i have to do it on the paginate on the controller.

I made somthing to show the ones whith the same region when i make a search on the search funtion but i cant do the same on the index funtion

**Edit**

i found how to set the url with the query to show what i want but now the pagination doesn't work, it shows all the results on one page, this is my index funtion:

```
    public function index()
{
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Languages', 'Categories', 'Users'],
        'limit' => 2
    ];
    $this->set('multimedia', $this->paginate($this->Multimedia));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['multimedia']);

            $multimedia = array();

    if (!empty($this->request->query)) {

        $country_id = $this->request->query['country_id'];

        $conditions = array(
           'AND' => array(
               'OR' => array(
                   'Multimedia.country_id' => $country_id,
                ),
                'AND' => array(
                )
            )
        );

        if ($country_id) $conditions['conditions']['or']['Multimedia.country_id'] = $country_id ;

        $multimedia = $this->Multimedia->find('all', $conditions);
    }
    $this->set('multimedia', $multimedia);

    $languages = $this->Multimedia->Languages->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $categories = $this->Multimedia->Categories->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $users = $this->Multimedia->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $multimedia_types = $this->Multimedia->Multimedia_types->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('multimedia', 'languages', 'categories', 'users', 'multimedia_types'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['multimedia']);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$multimedia = $this->Multimedia->find('all', $conditions)`, so of course you are getting all of the results. To [get paginated results](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-controller-paginate) instead, replace that line with

```
$this->paginate['conditions'] = $conditions;
$multimedia = $this->paginate($this->Multimedia);
```